# how to traverse specified subfolders in a windows batch file?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd

Here is my folder hierarchy:
[Numbers]
[Numbers/12545]
[Numbers/12545/dev]
[Numbers/12545/prod]

[Numbers/32445]
[Numbers/32445/dev]
[Numbers/32445/prod]

...

[Numbers/.....]
[Numbers/...../dev]
[Numbers/...../prod]

I want to copy some text files under the only "[Numbers/...../dev]" folders. How should i do?
I tried the below code and it's not work because it coppies under the all subfolders.

```
for /r %NUMBER_DIRS% %%d in (.) do (
    copy %PROJECT_INPUTS%\*.txt "%%d"
)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for /d /r "%NUMBER_DIRS%" %%d in (*DEV) do copy "%PROJECT_INPUTS%\*.txt" "%%~d\*.txt"
```

Comment: The question may not be understood. I want to copy the files of the %PROJECT_INPUTS% to the under [Numbers/...../dev] subfolders.

Comment: I believe you've got the `COPY` reversed...and you've not tackled the `\dev` directory requirement...

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (
  'dir /s /b /a:d "\numbers" ^| findstr /i /e "\dev"'
  ) do ECHO COPY %PROJECT_INPUTS%\*.txt "%%i\"
```

This will report what the batch **PROPOSES** to do. Remove the `ECHO` keyword before the `COPY` to execute the copy.

Note : you may need to add `/y` to the copy options if you want to **OVERWRITE** an existing file in the destination directories.

I presume that you're copying **FROM** `%PROJECT_INPUTS%` **TO** many `...\dev` directories.